# League Play Class Problems

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

When I play public matches online, I have my classes. When I go onto League play, though, my classes are reset, almost as if they are hacked. Does this happen often?  How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

No this is actually very logical as for treyarch wanted everybody playing in League play to have the same weapons and perks. So in league play you have all items, weapons and perks unlocked so it just comes down to how well you play the game. This is all explaned [HERE](http://www.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-black-ops-2/League_Play). As stated :

> All Weapons, Attachments, Equipment, and Scorestreaks will be available in Create A Class. Set up the perfect classes without having to reach level 55 first.

I hope this helped explain to you that you haven't been hacked but that its just treyarch their way of making league play more fair.

Comment: The only Public Match unlocks that are reflected in League play are Prestige Icons (used above players heads in game, but not in menu) and Gun Camos (you cannot equip Diamond if you have not unlocked it in Public Match first).

Answer (score 0):

The custom classes that you have in League Play are completely separate from that of public matches. Once you form your classes the way that you like them then they'll remain the same next time that you go into league play. The same goes with custom games, if you setup your classes for custom games they  will remain the same, but they are different classes than that in public matches or league play. This is setup that way because both in League Play and customs you have every attachment, gun, perks, and scorestreaks unlocked. Basically once you set them up you'll have them later if you choose to play again in league play. Keep in mind when you play in League you will not get progress toward camo challenges at all. If you have any questions about my answer then feel free to ask! Happy Gaming!